# warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data (C++)

Tags: c++, warnings

```
struct Vector {

    float i,j,k;

} std::vector pt[size];

... = ... + pt[temp];
```

`temp` is of type `int`. Compiler gives the warning as the title.

Comment: Please post as complete and valid code as possible. Your code is obviously invalid in many ways, so it is hard to know exactly which problem you are having.

Comment: Why have you replaced pieces of your example code with "..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this warning because the compiler is implicitly converting an `int` to a `float`.

A possible cause can be something like

```
int x = 7331;
float y = x;
```

Comment: but here the argument is `int`. So `pt[int]` should not give warning as at the end `pt[int]` is float.

Comment: @Shibli can you post your full expression and the exact line you get the warning at?

Comment: Here it gives error: `elm[e].cnt = elm[e].cnt + pt[dum_iElm[e-nBelm].vtx[i]] / nVtx3D;`

Comment: @Shibli: Since the warning is about the types of those variables, don't you realize that these are important? Also, are you sure the warning is not about conversion from float to int? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d7604yb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Shibli please edit the answer with the code and include the variable declarations - elm, e, pt, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say given that you've hidden much of the code, and we can't see the type of data that is stored in the std::vector, as you've either posted bad code or removed the template argument.

What is being added? Does `pt` store floats? A line like:

```
    float x = 5.0f;
    int y = 2 + x;
```

May generate this warning since there will be an implicit conversion of `x` to an int.